# how to know a component return null or element in react

Tags: reactjs

```
function A(){
  return null
}

function B({value}){
  if(!value){
     return null;
  }else{
     return <div>hello world</div>
  }
}

function App(){
    return <B value={<A/>}/>
}
```

as above, I want to render null in App, but render 'hello world'.
so, how to know a react component render a null or render a react element.

Answer (score 0):

do a check before rendering

```
function App(){
    return  <react.Fragment>
                    {B()?<B value={A()?<A/>:null}/>:null}
                 <react.Fragment>
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I just want to know the A's return result in B component